# Texturing Terrain in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make terrain in Unity and I have inserted the terrain object. I'm in texture paint and I've added a new terrain layer. I am trying to add a texture to the object in the view but it is not working and giving me the error: `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` I have tried looking it up but it gives me something to do with code, this has nothing to do with any code, just a terrain texture.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would share the details about how to reproduce the error along with screenshots of the terrain settings and the texture settings you want to add to the layer

Comment: Do you have textures set inside the texture paint panel of unity terrain. Try it out with a different texture. That error probably means one public variable is probably not assigned. Maybe it has nothing to do with terrain at all.

Comment: I know that it has something to do with the terrain because it says so in the console. And I’ll try it with a different texture.